# Add ordinal suffix to loop.index

Tags: templating, forloop

I'd like to add an ordinal suffix to the `loop.index` variable within a `for` loop.

For example:

```
1st
2nd
3rd
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd want to write a plugin that added an `|ordinal` Twig [filter](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/filters).

Then from your template, you would do: `loop.index|ordinal`.

The logic in the plugin would look something like:

```
public function ordinal($number)
{
    $ends = array('th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th');

    if ((($number % 100) >= 11) && (($number % 100) <= 13))
    {
        return $number.'th';
    }
    else
    {
        return $number.$ends[$number % 10];
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record, I had to Google what an ordinal suffix was.

Comment: So did I Brad...

Comment: Sorry about that. What should I have called it?

Comment: I'm sure that's the right word... just got to learn something new is all. :)

Comment: And thanks Brad, I'll try find some time figuring out how to add a plugin :)

Comment: Search for filter here: https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins and you'll find a bunch of plugins to get you started.

Comment: I've finally gotten around to creating [a plugin](https://github.com/katrinkerber/craft-ordinalize). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7):

This can also be done with a Twig macro, rather than creating a plugin:

```
{% macro ordinal(number) %}
    {%- spaceless %}
    {% if ((number % 100) >= 11) and ((number % 100) <= 13) %}
        {{ number }}th
    {% else %}
        {% set ends = ['th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th'] %}
        {{ number ~ ends[number % 10] }}
    {% endif %}
    {% endspaceless -%}
{% endmacro %}

{% from _self import ordinal %}

{% for entry in craft.entries %}
    <li>{{ ordinal(loop.index) }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Brandon. Is the an advantage/disadvantage to using a macro over a plugin?